# I want an route to learn EJB in easiest way?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

Migrating from PHP to EJB , I have previous experience of PHP , C++ , and plane concept of java.
But as i am reading EJB tutorials,I am not able to understand it properly.
I want some easiest tutorial through which i can learn EJB. Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java docs are still some of the best resources to learn .

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/

That said there is no easy way, the easiest is a lot of patience and hard work ;-)

Cheers!